# Issues with implementing combine functions and returning result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement CombineFunction

```
// Sync tasks
function f1(args,function() {  /* Does something */ });
function f2(args,function() {  /* Does something */ });
function f3(args,function() {  /* Does something */ });

const op = combineFxn([f1, f2,f3]);

// After combineFxn is combined, we need to invoke each of the 
// tasks function with 'test' arguments.
op('demo', function() {
    //cb
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

> - Implement combineFxn.
>
>   - This should return a function if invoked with `test` as an argument should invoke all the three function(s): 
>       `f1`, `f2` and `f3` with arguments.
> - The final response from `operation` should only be returned after all the tasks are finished
>
> All tasks are synchronous or async tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to compose tasks together and return a combined task.

Here is a way to do it that works with asynchronous tasks. You can use it to run synchronous tasks too but you will need to use `then` to get the result since everything is wrapped in a Promise:

```js
const combineTasks = (...tasks) => (...args) =>
  tasks.reduce(async (previous, task) => {
    const result = await previous;
    return task(result);
  }, Promise.resolve(...args));
  
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const f1 = x => x + 1;
const f2 = x => x * 2;

const f1Async = async (x) => {
  console.log(x);
  await delay(300);
  return x + 1;
};

const f2Async = async (x) => {
  console.log(x);
  await delay(300);
  return x * 2;
};

// Asynchronous task
const taskAsync = combineTasks(f1Async, f2Async, f1Async);
taskAsync(1).then(r => console.log(r));

// Synchronous task
const task = combineTasks(f1, f2, f1);
task(100).then(r => console.log(r));
```

If you want a synchronous API, you can do this:

```js
const combineTasks = (...tasks) => args =>
  tasks.reduce((prev, task) => task(prev), args);
  
const f1 = x => { console.log(x); return x + 1; };
const f2 = x => { console.log(x); return x * 2; };

const task = combineTasks(f1, f2, f1);
console.log(task(10));
```

Comment: Thank you .. what if it's only syncronous tasks .. do I still need async await?

Comment: @zer00ne, this is function returning a function, and the arguments will be packed in an array called tasks for the first function, and args for the inner function

Comment: @TechnoCorner, I will add an example

Comment: @TechnoCorner, you simply execute the callback in the last then, or you treat it as a regular task and add it as the last task, it will be given the result as argument